# Grep - PowerShell Style

Tags: split, powershell-3.0, select-string

I am having a hard time getting PowerShell to split a string after I "grep" it.  I really want to get the 10 largest values out of an hourly web log.

The "Grep" works, but I am not then able to split it:

> PS D:\Work\ps> D:\Work\ps\test\grep.ps1 Method invocation
>   failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] doesn't
>   contain a method named 'split'. At D:\Work\ps\test\grep.ps1:8 char:2
>   +  $string.split($separator,0, $option)
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

https://communary.net/2014/11/10/grep-the-powershell-way/
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/17/using-the-split-method-in-powershell/

```
 ##"[com.vendorStuff.utils.Stopwatch]"

 $string = select-string "execution \:" "D:\logs\server.log" -ca
 $separator = "execution \:"
 $option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
 $string.split($separator,1, $option)
 #$data.Split("execution \:")[1]
```

It is imporatnt to note: I have already escaped: 'execution :'
Couple of things that I have tried:

```
[string]$Data = sls 'execution \:' "D:\Work\ps\test\server.log" -ca
$data.split('execution \:')[1]
```

as well as:

```
$Data = (sls 'execution \:' "D:\Work\ps\test\server.log" -ca).tostring().split('execution \:')[1]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-split` parameter on a string.

```
$string = "oneToken execution :andAnotherToken"
$string -split "execution :" 
oneToken 
andAnotherToken
```

Comment: I was not very clear.  The string is already escaped..  It was originally: `"execution :" and is why I made it: `"execution \:"

Comment: I have modified the question to include the escape as well as things that I have tried.